# jwplayer6 subtitles heights setting

Tags: subtitle, jwplayer6

I recently added jwplayer to my site. I added video with subtitles. But when we do full screen subtitles are too low almost at the bottom. Is there anyway i can adjust it to appear higher.

Here my code:

```
<div id="myElement">Loading the player ...</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("myElement").setup({
        file: "/sample.mp4",
        height: 420,
        width: 950,
        tracks: [{ 
            file: "/sample.srt", 
            label: "English",
            kind: "captions",
            "default": true }]
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution will work for HTML5, I am not sure about flash though.

check this out [show-subtitle-outside-of-player](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15997784/show-subtitle-outside-of-player)

You need to catch the caption div and override the css