# Integrate Captions on Web Page with JWPlayer

Tags: javascript, jwplayer, closed-captions, webvtt

I am trying to implement Video Captions like at Lynda.com e.g. http://www.lynda.com/JavaScript-tutorials/Foundations-of-Programming-Fundamentals/83603-2.html

The captions run with the player and also in a block of HTML below the player. I am using JWPlayer for my video and know how to integrate it within the player. My question is how do I now display the full transcript below the video player and also do a live highlight while the Player is running the video? I am using WebVTT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could possibly use the HTML5 player, use our built in captions - http://support.jwplayer.com/customer/portal/articles/1407438-adding-closed-captions, and then use CSS to move the div outside of the video player space.

Comment: Could you please post a simple example if you it's not too much to ask?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15997784/show-subtitle-outside-of-player, essentially, .jwcaptions{    
position:absolute;bottom:0px;border:solid 2px #333;
-moz-border-radius: 15px;opacity:0.7;width:100% !important;bottom:0%
}, and #player_caption div{width:100% !important;text-align:center !important;left:0 !important;}